# Laravel delete query where is null

Tags: php, sql, laravel

So in the Registration table, in the controller i want make a query that if isg_option_extra_id is filled in in the form and the isg_options is not checked, delete the isg_option_extra_id
So if you first make a new record in the registration form, it adds the form but when you go to edit, it deletes the extra option if the extra isnt checked. if the extra is checked and the extraoption is filled in, its all fine.

I have tried "= null", but im not sure if thats the correct way to do it.

```
$registration= registration::where('isg_rand_id', $rand_id)
->where('isg_distance_id', $distance_id) 
->where('isg_category_id', $category_id)  
->where('isg_options', '=' , null); 
->where('isg_option_extra_id', '=' , $registration_options_extra)
->delete();
```

i now get an error saying:

> unexpected '->' delete.

any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#where-clauses) you should use `whereNull` eg.

```
->whereNull('isg_options')
```

To get rid of unexpected error remove `semicolon` after  this line:

```
->where('isg_options', '=' , null); //remove semicolon from here
```

Comment: nice eyes bro ! !

Answer (score 1):

The whereNull method verifies that the value of the given column is NULL.Discard Your Semicolon you will get your result or use whereNull

```
$registration= registration::where('isg_rand_id', $rand_id)
->where('isg_distance_id', $distance_id) 
->where('isg_category_id', $category_id)  
->whereNull('isg_options') 
->where('isg_option_extra_id', '=' , $registration_options_extra)
->delete();
```